# Share functions between frontend and backend (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a mean stack website. I have defined in the backend by mongoose the follows:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.user = mongoose.model('user', {
            name: String,
            email: String,
        }
    }

    getDisplayName = function (name, email) {
        if (name === null) return email; else return name
    }

    ... ...
}
```

Now, I want to, in the frontend, define the same function as `getDisplayName`. Does anyone know how to reuse it? I have other functions that I want to share between the frontend and backend.

Comment: There is a lot of ways of doing this. All time consuming.
Easiest is to just share the files with both projects.
Slightly easier is to use something like https://www.meteor.com/

Comment: It is in the same SPA mean-stack project...

Comment: This sort of thing is a design pattern issue.
As I mentioned, you can achieve this in a number of ways, but you got to ask yourself if it makes sense given your architecture.

I would advise you use something like https://www.meteor.com/ because the design pattern for things like this is done for you.

Comment: You could have a look at isomor: https://apiel.github.io/isomor/ . It's a tool I built recently to generate interface between backend and frontend automatically. There is an example with Angular and Nest https://apiel.github.io/isomor/#/Docs/getting-started/Angular